# Can no longer deploy to Bluemix Rules Engine Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules, jrules, ibm-odm

When I originally set up my Rules Engine service in Bluemix, I could deploy from my Eclipse Juno environment just fine.  I just tried to deploy a new project this morning, and I got the following error in the deployment report in Eclipse:

> ilog.rules.res.model.IlrAlreadyExistException: Unknown RuleApp: /RefillRulesApp/1.0. at
>   com.ibm.rules.res.internal.MutableRepositoryRESTAdapter.addRuleApp(MutableRepositoryRESTAdapter.java:86)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient$3.execute(RESClient.java:332)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient$3.execute(RESClient.java:1)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient.safeInvokeRES(RESClient.java:132)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient.deploy(RESClient.java:299)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.DsResRestClient.deploy(DsResRestClient.java:168)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.studio.model.decisionservice.impl.Server.deploy(Server.java:310)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.DsRuleAppDeployManager.deploy(DsRuleAppDeployManager.java:38)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.DsDeployManager.deploy(DsDeployManager.java:88)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsXOMDeploymentJob.deploy(SDsXOMDeploymentJob.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.deployRuleApp(SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.java:101)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.deploy(SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.java:65)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsXOMDeploymentJob.runInWorkspace(SDsXOMDeploymentJob.java:81)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)**

I checked the RES console server log and there isn't any untoward messages in it

The Decision Server version infomation looks like this:

> Version:  Decision Server 8.7.0.1 , Decision Engine 1.10.0 Patch level:   Build #2 on 2015-03-13 16:54:27 Release status: COMMERCIAL
>   Persistence Type: datasource (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10070) Startup
>   Time: Jan 29, 2016 4:17:18 PM GMT-05:00 Last Update Time: Feb 2, 2016
>   3:01:23 PM GMT-05:00

I checked for updates to the Eclipse plugin, and it looks like I am up to date.

If I check in the Explorer in the RES console, I can see that it partially deployed:
[Deploy Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7lvZ.jpg)

Notice how the rule app is greyed-out.

Any ideas?  Thanks...

Comment: I just tried re-deploying a rule project that I had deployed a few months ago and that deployed just fine, so the issue I am having is with new projects.

Comment: do you see the same issue when deploying a sample RuleApp to the service? Can you create a new RuleApp project with a different name which refers to the same rule project and try again? Can you give the instanceID you are working with?

Comment: Hi there.  The ID is brsv2-549940c2.  I get the same issue with any Rule App I try to deploy.  What does work is if I export the project and then deploy it manually from the RES console.  Thanks for the help...

Comment: Hi, can you delete the empty RuleApp before you try to deploy again? Do you see the stacktrace above when deploying any other RuleApp too? Is it possible for you to check your proxy/firewall settings in Eclipse (Window > Preferences > General > Network configuration). If this does not work please contact Bluemix support so they can work with you in detail.

Comment: Hi there.  Thanks, yes I did try deleting the RuleApp several times, as well as the XOM and other entries related to it.  However, I still got the same error.  There aren't any proxy settings that could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I deploy the RuleApp from a 'Rule project for Decision Service', I get the same error. Can you deploy it from a RuleApp project which references a 'Standard Rule Project'? That should fix the issue.

Comment: When I deploy a 'Classic' standard project, it works, but when I deploy a 'Decision Service' standard project, it doesn't.  However, I have several 'Decision Service' standard projects already deployed to my Bluemix RES, so I am still at a bit of a loss